# In-ValueProvider not Passing Data from ModuleDataSource (Blog App Mod)

Tags: 2sxc

I have taken the Blog App, added a Category ContentType as a field in the BlogPost ContentType and built a query to factor Category into the results.

But I am having trouble with the In-ValueProvider.  Following the example [here](https://2sxc.org/en/Docs-Manuals/Feature/feature/4544) the Visual Query Designer seems to be ignoring the incoming value from my ModuleDataSource.

[image: My Visual Query]

I have double checked the In-Stream name, my Entity names, case, TestParameters, etc. Are there any known bugs in 2sxc 8.44 and up that would cause this issue? What have I missed?

In this case I am using a RelationshipFilter. Relationship is "Category". Filter is "[In:Config:Category]". I can switch out to a [Querystring:Category] and that works fine and runs all my code.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a workaround.

It turns out that the In-ValueProvider is working but it's struggling with the *Category* of my *BlogPost* I think because *Category* is an entity.

For background I have a *BlogPost* ContentType, a *Category* ContentType, and an *Articles Home Header* ContentType.  *Articles Home Header* sets both the header info for the articles page and the *Category* entity.

For some reason the RelationshipFilter is having trouble comparing the *Category* entities between *Articles Home Header* and *BlogPost*. I tried the following for my Filter and neither worked:

[In:Config:Category]

[In:Config:Category:Title]

I wonder if this is a case sensitivity issue, a bug, or if I am just misunderstanding the filter syntax.

To work around I created a temp field called *TempCategory* in my *Articles Home Header* and used [In:Config:TempCategory] for the filter.

That worked.

For reference here is a snippet from the Query:

```
{
  "Config": [
    {
      "Title": "Coaching Articles",
      "SubTitle": "",
      "Image": "/Portals/0/uploadedimages/AcademicPrograms/Christ_College/crosswise-hero.jpg",
      "ImageAlt": "Crosswise stained glass",
      "Category": [
        {
          "Id": 2716,
          "Title": "Coaching"
        }
      ],
      "Id": 3118,
      "Modified": "2016-06-21T10:44:21.9Z",
      "_2sxcEditInformation": {
        "sortOrder": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "Paging": [
    {
      "Title": "Paging Information",
      "PageSize": 10,
      "PageNumber": 1,
      "ItemCount": 0,
      "PageCount": 0,
      "Id": 0,
      "Modified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "_2sxcEditInformation": {
        "entityId": 0,
        "title": "Paging Information"
      }
    }
  ],
,
  "Default": [
    {
      "Title": "Protect Your Players and Your Program: An Athletic Leader's Legal Duties",
      "UrlKey": "an-athletic-leaders-legal-duties",
      "PublishingGroup": null,
      "PublicationMoment": "2016-06-15T00:00:00Z",
      "Image": "/Portals/0/uploadedimages/AcademicPrograms/Graduate/Coaching/an_athletic_leaders_legal_duty.jpg",
      "ImageSquare": false,
      "Teaser": "<p>When the clock started on the new year earlier this month, all but one state joined the growing legal effort to protect and prevent concussions and head injuries among America&rsquo;s young.</p>",
      "Body": "<p><strong>When the clock started on the new year earlier this month,</strong> all but one state joined the growing legal effort to protect and prevent concussions and head injuries among America&rsquo;s young.</p>\n<p>As sports-related injuries and issues continue to dominate the headlines and influence programs throughout the country, laws like &ldquo;return-to-play&rdquo; are becoming a sign of the times when it comes to protecting players and athletic programs alike. The world of athletics is experiencing a significant shift in the perception of the roles and responsibilities of coaches, schools and athletic personnel.</p>",
      "DesignedContent": [],
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Id": 2576,
          "Title": "coaching"
        },
        {
          "Id": 2575,
          "Title": "management"
        },
        {
          "Id": 2574,
          "Title": "sports"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3035,
          "Title": "legal"
        }
      ],
      "Author": [
        {
          "Id": 3030,
          "Title": "Shaleek Blackburn"
        }
      ],
      "ImageAlt": "Referee holding a red",
      "Thumbnail": "",
      "ThumbnailAlt": "",
      "RelatedArticles": [
        {
          "Id": 2564,
          "Title": "Athletic Personnel's Duty To Warn"
        },
        {
          "Id": 2565,
          "Title": "Get A Better Grip On Bullying"
        },
        {
          "Id": 2717,
          "Title": "Good Coaching Develops Exceptional Athletes and People"
        }
      ],
      "Category": [
        {
          "Id": 2716,
          "Title": "Coaching"
        }
      ],
      "ArticleRelationships": null,
      "Id": 2513,
      "Modified": "2016-06-15T19:32:17.913Z",
      "_2sxcEditInformation": {
        "entityId": 2513,
        "title": "Protect Your Players and Your Program: An Athletic Leader's Legal Duties"
      }
    }  
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is just something that wasn't implemented in this detail yet

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I was wondering if many to many comparisons for the In-ValueProvider might simply not be coded yet.  That's OK.  We appreciate all you guys are doing.